# How to set point height on Y axis for specific series

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a case with Highcharts (xrange type) when I need to decsrease the height of points when there is no series for it. On the image https://i.stack.imgur.com/39YkM.jpg there is no any data for points W, S and S on Y axis. And the height should be lower for such cases. 
I dont have any idea how to implement such behavior

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
 yAxis: {
        gridLineWidth: 0
    },
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/bullet-graph/)

Comment: This one doesn't help. Height for grids 'T' and 'F' stay the same. In my case when T and F doesn't have any data I have to decrease the height of this empty grids
https://jsfiddle.net/zheleznov/0a2k5817/77/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `broken-axis` module to create unregular category widths. Currently it is also necessary to correct the labels postions:

```
chart: {
    type: 'xrange',
    events: {
        render: function() {
            var i = -1,
                tickPos,
                yAxis = this.yAxis[0],
                prevTickPos,
                categories = this.yAxis[0].categories;


            for (i; i < categories.length; i++) {
                if (i !== -1) {
                    tickPos = yAxis.ticks[i].mark.getBBox();
                    yAxis.ticks[i].label.attr({
                        y: tickPos.y - (tickPos.y - prevTickPos.y) /
                            2 + yAxis.ticks[i].label.getBBox().height / 2
                    });
                }

                prevTickPos = tickPos || yAxis.ticks[i].mark.getBBox();
            }
        }
    }
},
yAxis: {
    ...,
    tickWidth: 1,
    breaks: [{
        from: 1,
        to: 2,
        breakSize: 0.5
    }]
},
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/u28tmbh6/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.breaks

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.render